# How to calculate proportion display pie chart in pandas or others?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65021427/how-to-calculate-total-amount-by-pandas-groupby-number-and-unit-price), I would like to get the proportion of item in total amount, and display a pie chart like below(need to display the name and the proportion of the item):

[image: screenshot]

I use the same dataset as the question:

```
id      date    num     name    desc    price
1   7/6/2020    10      pen     abcd     $1
1   7/6/2020    2       abc     efg      $3
1   7/6/2020    3       bcd     efg      $5
2   7/6/2020    3       pen     abcd     $1
2   7/6/2020    1       pencil  abcd     $3
2   7/6/2020    2       disk     abcd    $1
2   7/6/2020    2       paper    abcd    $1
3   7/6/2020    2       ff       pag     $100
3   7/6/2020    10      water    kml     $5
4   7/15/2020   5       gg       kml     $5
4   7/15/2020   10      cofffee  oo      $5
5   7/15/2020   5       pp      oo       $4
6   7/15/2020   2       abc    efg        $3
6   7/15/2020   3       bcd    efg        $5
6   7/15/2020   4       aa      efg        $5
6   7/15/2020   5       bb       efg        $6
7   7/15/2020   1       bag       abcd      $50
7   7/15/2020   1       box      abcd       $20
8   7/15/2020   1       pencil    abcd      $3
8   7/15/2020   2       disk     abcd      $1
8   7/15/2020   2       paper    abcd      $1
8   7/15/2020   2       ff       hijk     $100
9   8/15/2020   10      water    kml     $5
9   8/15/2020   5       gg        kml     $5
9   8/15/2020   10      cofffee   oo     $5
9   8/15/2020   5       pp       oo       $4
9   8/15/2020   2       abc      efg        $3
10  8/15/2020   3       bcd      efg        $5
10  8/15/2020   4       aa        efg        $5
10  8/15/2020   5       bb        efg        $6
11  8/15/2020   1       bag       abcd      $50
11  8/15/2020   1       box       abcd      $20
```

I would like to use matplotlib, pycharts  and any other packages are fine, My code as below is not correct:

```
import pandas as pd
import xlrd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_excel ('./orders.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')
df.groupby(by=['name']).sum()


df['price'] = df['price'].replace('$','', regex=True).astype(int)
df['new'] = df['price'].mul(df['num'])

df1 = df.groupby(by=['name'], as_index=False)['new'].sum()

# df1
# df1['new'] = df1.apply(lambda x: x.sum(), axis=1)
# df1.loc['new'] = df1.apply(lambda x: x.sum()).dropna()
# df1
# data = df1.Series(???)
# # print(data)

# from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties   
# # myfont=FontProperties(fname=r'C:/Windows/Fonts/simhei.ttf',size=14)
# # sns.set(font=myfont.get_name())

# plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (8.0, 6.0)   

# lbs= data.index
# explodes=[0.1 if i=='??' else 0 for i in lbs]
# plt.pie(data, explode=explodes,labels=lbs, autopct="%1.1f%%",
#                                 colors=sns.color_palette("muted"),startangle = 90,pctdistance = 0.6,
#           textprops={'fontsize':14,'color':'black'})


# plt.axis('equal')  

# plt.show()
```

Comment: Please update the question with a sample of the dataset, as the issue (question) is currently not reproducible.  And please clarify *exactly* where you are stuck.  Thank you.

Comment: @jezrael Hi, could you please help me with this question?

Comment: If you’d like to use Plotly, this is calculated and can be displayed automatically, by their pie graph.

Comment: @S3DEV could you please tell me how to display it, actually I don't know how to calculate, `df1.loc['new']`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pandas internal plot function, which most likely uses matplotlib backend:

```
s = df.groupby('name')['new'].sum()

ax = s.plot.pie(figsize=(10,10), autopct='%.2f%%')
```

Or chain together:

```
ax = (df.groupby('name')['new'].sum()
        .plot.pie(figsize=(10,10), autopct='%.2f%%')
     )
```

Then `ax` is a Matplotlib axis instance and you get:

[image]

Comment: Do you know how to display in Chinese?

Comment: Have a look at [this blog post](https://jdhao.github.io/2017/05/13/guide-on-how-to-use-chinese-with-matplotlib/).

Comment: Hi, do you know how to display daily histogram by pandas result in pyecharts or others? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65025576/how-to-display-daily-histogram-by-pandas-result-in-pyecharts-or-others