# How to display daily histogram by pandas result in pyecharts or others?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65021427/how-to-calculate-total-amount-by-pandas-groupby-number-and-unit-price), I would like to get the proportion of item in total amount by id in July, I use the same dataset as the question:

```
    id       date  num     name  type price
0    1   7/6/2020   10      pen  abcd    $1
1    1   7/6/2020    2      abc   efg    $3
2    1   7/6/2020    3      bcd   efg    $5
3    2   7/6/2020    3      pen  abcd    $1
4    2   7/6/2020    1   pencil  abcd    $3
5    2   7/6/2020    2     disk  abcd    $1
6    2   7/6/2020    2    paper  abcd    $1
7    3   7/6/2020    2       ff   pag  $100
8    3   7/6/2020   10    water   kml    $5
9    4  7/15/2020    5       gg   kml    $5
10   4  7/15/2020   10  cofffee    oo    $5
11   5  7/15/2020    5       pp    oo    $4
12   6  7/15/2020    2      abc   efg    $3
13   6  7/15/2020    3      bcd   efg    $5
14   6  7/15/2020    4       aa   efg    $5
15   6  7/15/2020    5       bb   efg    $6
16   7  7/15/2020    1      bag  abcd   $50
17   7  7/15/2020    1      box  abcd   $20
18   8  7/15/2020    1   pencil  abcd    $3
19   8  7/15/2020    2     disk  abcd    $1
20   8  7/15/2020    2    paper  abcd    $1
21   8  7/15/2020    2       ff  hijk  $100
22   9  8/15/2020   10    water   kml    $5
23   9  8/15/2020    5       gg   kml    $5
24   9  8/15/2020   10  cofffee    oo    $5
25   9  8/15/2020    5       pp    oo    $4
26   9  8/15/2020    2      abc   efg    $3
27  10  8/15/2020    3      bcd   efg    $5
28  10  8/15/2020    4       aa   efg    $5
29  10  8/15/2020    5       bb   efg    $6
30  11  8/15/2020    1      bag  abcd   $50
31  11  8/15/2020    1      box  abcd   $20
```

I would like to display daily histogram of total amount by type in pyecharts or others, it's similar like [image: this screenshot], below code is not correct,

```
import pandas as pd
import xlrd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_excel ('./orders.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')
df.groupby(by=['type']).sum()


df['price'] = df['price'].replace('$','', regex=True).astype(int)
df['new'] = df['price'].mul(df['num'])

df1 = df.groupby(by=['name'], as_index=False)['new'].sum()

# df1
# df1['new'] = df1.apply(lambda x: x.sum(), axis=1)
# df1.loc['new'] = df1.apply(lambda x: x.sum()).dropna()
```

Thanks so much for any advice.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you are trying to do?

Comment: Do you know how to select data of July?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma All I need right now is only select dataframe by monthly.

Comment: I think you can try `july_df = df[pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.month.eq(7)].copy()`

Comment: @ShubhamSharma Yes, yes, yes, you are right!!!! It works finally, thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Happy coding..!

Answer (score 0):

First off, I recommend using `datetime` type to handle date/time:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

Now, to answer your question, if you only want the July data, you can extract it with:

```
July_df = df[df['date'].dt.to_period('M')=='2020-07'].copy()
```

and you can go on  with the plotting of `July_df`.

If you want to plot for every month, you can use `groupby`:

df['total'] = df['price'].str.replace('$','').astype(float)*df['num']

```
(df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='date',freq='M'),'name'])['total'].sum()
   .reset_index(level='date')
   .groupby('date')
   .plot.pie(subplots=True, autopct='%.2f%%')
)
```

And you would get two plots like these:

[image]

[image]

You can also add some more formatting if you iterate the groupby:

```
# notice the difference in first groupby
groups = (df.groupby([df.date.dt.strftime('%b-%Y'),'name'])['total'].sum()
   .reset_index(level='date')
   .groupby('date')
)
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(10,5))
for ax, (month, data) in zip(axes, groups):
    data['total'].plot.pie(autopct='%.2f%%', ax=ax)
    ax.set_title(f'data in {month}')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: hi, thanks so much for your detailed answer, I would like to display histogram like screenshot, I already updated my question, thanks again for reading my question.